# Changing min & max values of multiple JQueryUI sliders on a page from Select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

I have a page. It has many JQueryUI sliders. The value of these sliders can be set by text box or by manually dragging the slider. The min & max values of the sliders can be set by changing an option in a drop-down menu, eg:

```
     Select slider:
<select class="dropdown" id="slider3_select">
    <option value="1" data-low="1" data-high="50">Sips</option>
    <option value="2" data-low="1" data-high="25">Cups</option>
    <option value="3" data-low="1" data-high="10">Litres</option>
</select>
```

The JQuery I am using to get the data-low & data-high values above, and update the slider based on them, is:

```
     $('.dropdown').change(function(){
        var selector = ("#" + $(this).parent().find(".slider").attr("id")),
        currentVal = parseInt($(selector).slider("value")),
        newBegin = $(this + "option:selected").data("low"),
        newEnd = $(this + "option:selected").data("high");
        $(selector).slider({
        value: currentVal,
        min: newBegin,
        max: newEnd
        });
      });
```

This works properly for the first slider on the page, but fails for the subsequent sliders- on these, the value of newBegin & newEnd fails to update. I guess that I am targeting either the select .dropdown or the option:selected incorrectly, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

### [See the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SbZcf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your code this:

```
newBegin = $(this + "option:selected").data("low"),
newEnd = $(this + "option:selected").data("high");
```

with this:

```
newBegin = $(this).find("option:selected").data("low"),
newEnd = $(this).find("option:selected").data("high");
```

You need to use the [`selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) properly in jQuery.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbZcf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this + "option:selected")
```

This isn't a valid selector. Basically you're trying to concatenate an element with a string, it's just not going to work.

You could do `$(this).find('option:selected')`